# Fix Highcharts dataLabels to the bottom

Tags: highcharts

I've been searching and I can't find an easy way to fix the Highcharts dataLabels to the bottom of the graphic. What I'm looking for is something like the following, for the column chart:

```
 80 -  ┌──┐        ┌──┐ ┌──┐
 40 -  |  | ┌──┐   |  | |  |
  0 -|_|__|_|__|_|_|__|_|__|_|
        80   40     80   80
         Cat 1       Cat 2
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate on each elemetn, and use translate function, which allows to "move" SVG elements.

```
var bottom = chart.plotHeight - 20;

    $.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,data){

        data.dataLabel.attr({
            y: bottom
        });
    });
```

Take look at the simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wMLg6/39/

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Too bad there isn't an easier way without having to re-calculate positions.

Answer (score 2):

I think code below helps you. `stacking` is the trick. change `y` value according to your chart.

```
plotOptions:{

    column:{
        stacking:'normal',
    dataLabels:{
        enabled:true,
        verticalAlign:'bottom',
        y:40
    }
    },
},
```

Comment: This code sure seems to work, but It only works properly when I don't work with series. In my case scenario, the input data is not static and must support series without stacking. This position also only applies to the not-stacked version, as when results are stacked, they are on the right position by default. Thank you for your input.